# Unable to store pcm audio in .mp4 container file

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, containers, mp4, libavformat

Is it possible to store a pcm audio file into .mp4 file?

I used ffmpeg command  "ffmpeg -i tempA.wav -acodec copy temp.mp4" but unable to store it in mp4 container file.

> Input #0, wav, from 'tempA.wav':
>
> Duration: 00:01:36.51, bitrate: 128 kb/s
>
> ```
> Stream #0.0: Audio: pcm_s16le, 8000 Hz, 1 channels, s16, 128 kb/s
> ```
>
> [mp4 @ 0x7d70e0] Tag [1][0][0][0]/0x00000001 incompatible with output
>   codec id '65536'
>
> Output #0, mp4, to 'temp.mp4':
>
> ```
> Stream #0.0: Audio: pcm_s16le, 8000 Hz, 1 channels, 128 kb/s
> ```
>
> Stream mapping:
>
> Stream #0.0 -> #0.0
>
> Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters
>   ?)

Where in converting to **.AVI** (ffmpeg -i tempA.wav -acodec copy temp.avi) 
& **.MOV** (ffmpeg -i tempA.wav -acodec copy temp.mov) file formats works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 10):

I don't think mp4 container format support raw pcm audio. You will have to use either avi or mov.
See wikipedia link for supported audio format for mp4 container

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_container_formats

Also follow doom9 forum link.

http://forum.doom9.org/archive/index.php/t-140877.html

Official page

http://mpeg.chiariglione.org/standards/mpeg-4/audio

Comment: This used to be the case but not anymore. See my answer below. Also note that chiariglione is not the official page anymore. Now its https://www.mpeg.org

Answer (score 2):

The previous answer is not correct anymore [ISO/IEC 23003-5](https://www.iso.org/standard/77752.html) defines the storage of uncompressed audio in mp4. But it is quite new and I am not sure if some tools already implemented it or not.